# change fragment by swiping or pushing button differences

Tags: android, android-fragments, swipe

I have activity that has 3 fragments. When I'm switching fragments by swiping everything is ok. But on my **Fragment 2** I have button that must set current fragment **Fragment 1**. By pushing this button it changes the fragment with some problems expressed in pics [image: pics] when normal on is [image: that]. Something similar [image: here]  which normal one is [image: that] . It works correct on devices with higher performance. How to solve this problem and with what exactly this problem connected?

Button Listener is

```
OnClickListener btnListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).changeFragment(2);
        }
    };
```

Also here is some info about my `MainActivity`

```
MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements CLFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, FMFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener
```

and also

```
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            if (position == 0) {
                return new CLFragment();
            } else if (position == 1) {
                return new VFragment();
            } else {
                return FMFragment.newInstance();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return page_count;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using view pager ?

Comment: I'v added some more info. What about view pager I'm not using it.